# VirusTotal API via PHP CURL gives error 'empty filename'

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

So I am uploading file via

`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.

After upload I need to send the file to [virustotal API](https://developers.virustotal.com/reference#files-scan) for scanning.

But I get the error:

```
{ "error": { "message": "Received file with an empty filename. Please post with filename.", "code": "BadRequestError" } }
```

Here is my code. I don't understand how I am posting the file incorrectly:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // enter here the path of the file to be scanned
    $target_dir = "files/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $file_to_scan = "https://webbasedapplication.dreamhosters.com/" . $target_file;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.<hr>";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.<hr>";
    }
    $post_url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files';
    $post['file'] = '@'.$file_to_scan;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $headers = [
        'x-apikey: 12345abcde',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $api_reply = curl_exec($ch);
    print $api_reply;
}
```

P.S. File is uploading successfully on server.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That gives the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using @ to upload files with curl was deprecated in 5.5, stopped working by default in 5.6, and was completely removed in 7.0

either downgrade to PHP <=5.5, or replace

```php
    $post['file'] = '@'.$file_to_scan;
```

with

```php
    $post['file'] = new CURLFile($file_to_scan);
```

also get rid of

```
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
```

- let libcurl generate it for you, the actual header is supposed to look like

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------718e1fbbd5629679
```

- with a boundary generated by curl.